# Joomla or cakePHP for designing application without limitation?

Tags: cakephp, joomla

I've only touched the top of the iceberg of Joomla and cakePHP. There is so much to learn. But on top of learning I want to build something useful as well.

Joomla is the easiest to set up and is very agile if I wanted to get things up and running with concepts that are already in use out there. That is, I can install different components and extensions that are developed by other uses. The problem here is that I'm limited to other people's imagination and vision. What if I wanted something specific and no components or extension meets my needs, I would need to build my own. Which brings me to the question: -

Should I learn how to develop custom components/extensions in Joomla, or learn cakePHP to truly be capable of engineering my own application to suit all my needs?

Here is the application that I want to build through my learning - an integration of all of the below component each able to interact with one another:

- A blog
- A forum
- A user participating recipe book
- User calendar
- Image gallery

Yes there is alot that I want to do, but it's all in the name of learning. I really want to be able to have an application which has an integration of all the above components which works smoothly together. For example, when a user submits a recipe or a blog this is written to their Calendar. Another example, user will be able to share their recipe/image gallery within their blog, without the reader having to navigate away. Another example, images can be tagged with recipe or ingredients of the recipe.

I'm starting on a clean slate, so I'm really looking for some opinion on which one I should stick to to achieve what I want to do. And which one will have a steeper learning curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a forum, you could use [Kunena](http://kunena.org).

[Image Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery), [Blog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog) and [User Calendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events) should be easy enough to find.

As for the Recipe Book, if you are willing to purchase an extension then the [ZOO](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/apps/index.php?option=com_zoo&view=frontpage&Itemid=7) app by Yootheme might be an idea, or you could allow users to submit standard Joomla articles and use a comments component such as [JComment](http://www.joomlatune.com/jcomments-downloads.html#avatars)